# Cannot find module 'sequelize/types/lib/hooks' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, express, sequelize-typescript

Getting this error while building:

```
node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/hooks/shared/hook-meta.d.ts:2:32 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'sequelize/types/lib/hooks' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import { SequelizeHooks } from 'sequelize/types/lib/hooks';
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/hooks/shared/hooks-service.d.ts:4:32 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'sequelize/types/lib/hooks' or its corresponding type declarations.

4 import { SequelizeHooks } from 'sequelize/types/lib/hooks';
```

**Package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.4",
    "@types/sequelize": "^4.28.11",
    "ajv": "^8.8.2",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "errorhandler": "^1.5.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^6.0.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.2",
    "pg": "^8.7.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "sequelize": "^6.11.0",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.3.0",
    "sequelize-typescript": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/errorhandler": "^1.5.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.6",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.11",
    "@types/validator": "^13.7.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.5.0",
    "eslint": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "prettier": "^2.5.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
  }
```

I have tried upgrading version of sequelize, sequelize-cli and sequelize-typescript to latest one, but it is still not working.

Please do let me know, where I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Did you install `Sequelize` version that matches a version that is required by `sequelize-typescript`

Comment: @Anatoly I have updated my question ( attached package.json dependencies ).

Comment: Can you look at `package.json` in `node_modules/sequelize-typescript` folder and look at `sequelize` version?

Comment: "sequelize": "6.8.0"

Comment: Exactly that? Not "sequelize": "^6.8.0"?

Comment: Yes, I matched it with the version in my `package.json`.
Its working now.

Comment: The directory changed in sequelize v6 from `sequelize/types/lib/hooks` to `sequelize/types/hooks`. sequelize-typscript needs to catch up. It would appear this will be in the next sub-version: https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript/pull/1202
Meanwhile, I've modified my node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/hooks/shared/hook-meta.d.ts file to `import { SequelizeHooks } from 'sequelize/types/lib/hooks';`

Comment: More here: https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript/issues/1198

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the library `sequelize-typscript` has been updated to solve this problem in version 2.1.3. https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript/commit/ab45c14da8cbd388f7611c0703e1f198e1f4541b

Answer (score 5):

In your *.model.ts files, replace

`import { HookReturn } from 'sequelize/types/lib/hooks';`

by

`import { HookReturn } from 'sequelize/types/hooks';`

[image]

Comment: Thanks.
For me changing from `import { Json } from "sequelize/types/lib/utils";` to `import { Json } from "sequelize/types/utils";` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in sequelize-typescript 2.1.3

https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript/commit/ab45c14da8cbd388f7611c0703e1f198e1f4541b